# JavaScript can't read my toggle (it shows an error)

Tags: javascript, html

When I try To function the hamburger using the code:

```
burger = document.querySelector('.burger')
navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar')
navlist = document.querySelector('.nav-list')


burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
navbar.ClassList.toggle('v-class-resp');
nav-list.classlist.toggle('v-class-resp');

})
```

It show me the error `Can't read toggle (reading 'toggle)`.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css">
    
    <title>SG Network</title>
    
</head>
<body  >
    
    <nav class="navbar background h-nav-resp" >
        <ul class="nav-list v-class-resp">
            <div class="logo" style="border: 60px;"> <img src="Add a heading.jpg" alt="Logo"> </div>
            <li> <a href="#HomePage">HomePage</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#About us">About us</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#Buy-Ranks">Buy Ranks</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#Donate">Donate</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#Vote">Vote</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#Discord">Discord</a></li><h1></h1>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="firstsection background">
<div class="box background">
<div class="firsthalf "> <p class="text-big">SG NetWork Is A Network blah blah blah blah blah vlah vlah
     vlah blah vlah vlah blah vlah vlah blah vlah vlah blah vlah vlah blah vlah vlah blah vlah
      vlah blah vlah vlah blah vlah vlah blah vlah vlah blah 

            
</p>
<div class="button">
    <button class="btn">Vote</button>
    <button class="btn">Discord</button>
</div>
 </div>
<div class="secondhalf ">

    
</div>
</div>

<p>
    <footer class="foot background">Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserverd</footer>
    </p>

    <script src="resp.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Image:

[image]

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: You need lowercase the letter c in `navbar.ClassList`

Comment: Be more careful with case and names. `ClassList` is not `classlist` is not `classList`, and `nav-list` is not `navlist`. The `-` in `nav-list` is considered a minus operator in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language, meaning you can't type `ClassList`, you can't type `classlist`, you have to type `classList`. Also, you can't type `nav-list.classList`, you have to type `navlist.classList` because you defined it as `navlist`, not `nav-list` and `-` is not allowed in variable names.

Comment: i am still getting a error can we talk in discord?

Comment: sure! what's your username + tag?

Comment: Atharva#0179 my name = tag

Comment: I sent you a friend request.

Comment: *`-` is not allowed in variable names* That is only true for local variables. For global variables like the ones OP has shown, a variable name can contain any valid UTF-8 character; if it contains problematic characters like `-` oder spaces, you'll have to reference those using that bracket notation.

Comment: @connexo What bracket notation?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation

Comment: @connexo Oh, but you'll have to do `window["hello-world"] = "value"` but OP used something like `hello-world = "value"`, which doesn't work.

Comment: @AtharvaKotecha: asking for private contact details is technically permitted here, but it is not the point of Stack Overflow. The purpose we are trying to achieve is to create quality questions that will be useful to other people, and the best way to create those is to collaborate in public.